# Why is my query not pushing to this nested array?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to push a new object to a nested array with Mongoose. I've tried different methods and saw similar posts, but I seem to be missing something. Here is the schema I created:

```
var board = new Schema({
    boardId: String,
    columns: [
        {
            id: String,
            name: String,
            tasks: [
                {
                    id: String,
                    title: String,
                    description: String,
                    severity: String,
                    client: String
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
});
```

Here is what an object looks like in my database:

```
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"xxxx"
   },
   "boardId":"xxxx",
   "columns":[
      {
         "id":"xxxx",
         "name":"todo",
         "tasks":[
            
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"xxxx",
         "name":"doing",
         "tasks":[
            
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"xxxx",
         "name":"done",
         "tasks":[
            
         ]
      }
   ],
   "__v":{
      "$numberInt":"0"
   }
}
```

I'm essentially trying to push a new task given a boardId and column's id. Here is my current implementation:

```
Board.findOneAndUpdate(
        { 
            "boardId": boardId,
            "columns.id": columnId
        },
        {
            "$push": {
                "columns.$.tasks": task
            }
        }
    );
```

I'm wondering if it has something to do with me using internally generated ids, although other queries that I've used against boardId have worked. I do plan to migrate to just using _id at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Small issue, it turns out that I needed to add a callback to my query. Once I did that, it successfully pushed the object to the right array.

Example code here:

```
Board.findOneAndUpdate(
    { 
        boardId: boardId,
        "columns.id": columnId
    },
    {
        $push: {
            "columns.$.tasks": task
        }
    },
    (res) => {
        console.log(res);
    }
);
```